# The Odin Project -- Google Homepage Project

Tags: html, css

I've been working on the The Odin Project for the last week and I just came across the first web development project: to code Google's homepage using HTML and CSS. I've finished my attempt, but I'd like to get some feedback on my code to make sure that I'm not falling into some pitfall and learning bad habits. If you know HTML or CSS, please give me some feedback!
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href= "styles.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>

  <header>
    <ul class="topNavbar">
      <li class = "about" style="padding-left: 0;"> About </li>
      <li class = "store"> Store </li>
      <li class = "signIn"> Sign In </li>
      <li class = "images"> Images </li>
      <li class = "gmail"> Gmail </li>
    </ul>
  </header> 

  <body>
    <center>
      <img 
      src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
      alt = "Google logo, no doodle"
      class = "logo">

      <div class = "search "> </div>
      <div class = "googleSearch"> Google Search </div>
      <div class = "feelingLucky"> I'm Feeling Lucky </div>
    </center>
  </body>

  <footer>
    <ul class="bottomNavbar">
      <li class = "advertising" style="padding-left: 5px;"> Advertising </li>
      <li class = "business"> Business </li>
      <li class = "howSearchworks"> How Search works </li>
      <li class = "settings"> Settings </li>
      <li class = "terms"> Terms </li>
      <li class = "privacy"> Privacy </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .logo {
    position: static;
    padding-top: 109px;
}

.search{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
    border-radius: 24px;
    width: 482px; 
    height: 44px;

    margin: 0 auto;
}

.googleSearch {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;

    position: relative;
    right: 100px;
    top: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;

    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #5F6368;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.googleSearch:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    color: #222;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.feelingLucky {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;

    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 13px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;

    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #5F6368;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.feelingLucky:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    color: #222;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.topNavbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.topNavbar > li {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.gmail {
    float: right; 
}

.images {
    float: right;
}
.signIn{
    float: right;   
}

.bottomNavbar {
    position: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 880px;
    margin-left: -27px;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    
    line-height: 40px;
}

.bottomNavbar > li {
    padding-left: 27px;
}

.privacy{
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
    float: right; 
}
.terms{
    float: right; 
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
.settings{
    float: right; 
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}

li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I'm also new to Stackoverflow, so please feel free to tell me if I didn't follow typical posting style.

Comment: Post to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: Does it produce the correct output?

Comment: @Mast roughly. There were a couple of things that I couldn't figure out exactly how to code. It looks mostly the same though -- at least to my eyes haha.

Comment: Side note, don't use `<center>` it's obsolete. Also, you closed your body element (`</body>`) too early

Comment: @j08691 Should I have centered those elements in css instead? Also, should I have closed the </body> after </footer>? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, the footer is part of the body, not separate like the header.

Comment: header, /header, body, footer, /footer, /body